# Why doesn't this oscillator oscillate

Tags: oscillator

[image]

According to the solution, it says it's because the phase shift is wrong. The gain network is non-inverting, so I assume that means that the LC feedback network was not 0 degrees for that particular frequency.

So I tried to work it out by hand but I am stuck here. Is my knowledge that the LC feedback not being 0 degrees for f = 1/root(2LC) the reason why it doesn't work? If so, what is the shift exactly, and how can I calculate the phase shift from the equations below

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the Wien bridge oscillator circuit: -

[image]

It is very similar to the oscillator in the question except that the lower capacitor is is an inductor in the question. At this point alarm bells should possibly start ringing to inform you that replacing the cap with an inductor will not work.

However, lets look at the frequency and phase response of the RC Wien bridge network. This is the filter section of the Wien bridge oscillator circuit (C2 is replaced by L in the question): -

[image]

Here's the phase response: -

[image]

As can be seen, at resonance, the phase shift is zero as one expects - this produces oscillation at Fr. With C2 changing to an inductor, the phase shift will be 90 degrees and will therefore not oscillate. This last point presumes you understand what happens when L and C are combined at resonance. If not then look on [this](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/RLCtool.php) page for a simulation.

Comment: Nice, (+1) It's most likely in your links, but @Raaj also has to adjust the gain resistors to over come the 1/3 drop in amplitude.

Comment: For my opinion, it is problematic to compare both circuits, because replacing C2 by an inductor gives a HIGHPASS which hardly can be compared with a classical bandpass response.(By the way: Not WEIN but WIEN!).

Comment: Ah I get it..its a high pass filter, hence the 90 degree phase shift at fr

Comment: I wish however, I could understand the math it takes to derive that 90 degrees.

Comment: @LvW WIEN oops my mistake and shall be corrected.

Comment: @Raaj, look into my answer (transfer function) and verify what happens at the frequency w=wo: Only the middle part of the denominator with "s=jw" is there (pure imaginary). This is identical to 90 deg phase shift.

Comment: @Andyaka If I connect the inductor , the cap and the non inverting input in series , will this oscillate ?

Comment: @AnirudhGanesh It looks like it would be it would be so easy to try in something like LTSpice so, if you give it a go come back and let me know because I'd be interested. The ratio of the resistors needs to be right and there is still the basic problem of amplitude control to consider (as with any Wien bridge oscillator or this new idea).

Comment: @Andyaka I tried something similar , it refuses to start oscillating

Comment: @Andyaka https://imgur.com/a/SxiWn

Comment: @Andyaka Your comment made me think of the gain , I let it be 1 +1/10 and it started oscillating at the expected frequency ! IT WORKS ! but it doesn't go all the way through , the oscillating is limited to a few milivolts

Comment: You need a resistor from the non-inverting input to mid-rail/0 volts/gnd to correctly bias the input.

Comment: @Andyaka Like this ? https://imgur.com/a/WjIZz , Also , I was wrong about the frequency , it seems to be off by several orders of magnitude , the decimals were close to 1/(2 pi) so I thought it was right , but no . The frequency on the simulation is 1.59 Megahertz

Comment: I can't read the L and C values because you have them overlapped. Also try the resistor at about 1 kohm or it won't be very resonant - series resonance achieves higher Q with a lower value load resistor but you can't go too low or the op-amp won't be able to drive it.

Comment: @Andyaka oh sorry, I'm using a 1uF cap and a 1H inductor (all fine in theory right?). And can you please ping me for a response next time? I was kinda waiting. Also,  turning that resistor to 1k stopped the oscillations completely and changing the gain to 2 made it oscillate at 148 Hz?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52087/discussion-between-vrisk-and-andy-aka).

Answer (score 1):

Because your handwriting is not easy to read I didn`t follow your calculation in detail - however, the denominator of the transfer function for the RLC feedback circuit cannot be **real** for finite frequencies (the **imaginary** part cannot be zero for s=jw). However, this is required to have a zero phase at a finite frequency - as a precondition for producing oscillations. Hence, the circuit cannot work as a n oscillator. (The imag. part of the transfer function always must contain a **difference** in order to become zero for a finite frequency).

EDIT 1: The transfer functionof the RLC feedback path is **H(s)=N(s)/D(s)** with

**N(s)=LCs^2**  and  **D(s)=1+s(L/R+RC)+2LCs^2**

EDIT 2:  OK - I have tried to follow your calculation. It is correct, and - as expected - it is the transfer function of a second-order highpass (phase starts at +180 deg and approaches zero for infinite frequencies).